# Is there a way we can set the date picker value to System date

Tags: datepicker

Is there a way we can set the date picker value to System date (it usually defaults to set date i.e. 01/01/0001)

Appreciate your help on this!!

Comment: I use silverlight 5 with using oracle connectivity

Comment: You may try `dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Today;`

Comment: Hi Thanks for replaying but for my problem its not working because  I want to use it with out datetimepicker can define me on other way with out using datetimepicker..

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax

```
dateTimePicker1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);
```